# How to delete a Rectangular Grid without deleting the color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to the use of the Rectangular Grid Tool and I created an 8-bit style background using it and the LivePaint Bucket. I'm afraid that some how, some of the lines of the grid were colored and are now showing through the image. I had the grid stroke set to none, so I'm not really sure how this happened.
Allow me to show you:
[image: the background]

As you can imagine, this was not desired effect. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you select all and set the stroke color to none?

Comment: The stroke is already set to none, as you see it.

Comment: Then you're in for some work. All those areas much be shapes then. It will require you to go through and recolor the mis-colored areas.

Comment: Ugh. That is ridiculously infuriating, seeing as how it won't allow me to select the miscolored areas >.<

Comment: Are all of the individual squares still discreet, or are they merged with the grid-lines?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what it looks like zoomed way in on one of the trouble areas?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this for a long time.

So I guess you did the same, painted it in, then expanded. After that:

- select the whole thing -> on the upper right TRANSFORM -> Align to
  pixel grid.

It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is three years later, but I've been having this problem as well and I've found the solution!

Simply select the grid, then select 'Object' > Rasterize and in the background box check 'Transparent.'

That worked for me, hope this helps!!

Answer (score -5):

Hi you have to expand the live paint effect Select the art > Objects > Live paint > expand ...the tinny lines don´t disappear at all